# Probability that the sum of N dice is at least X

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

> If N fair 6 sided dice are thrown, what is the probability that the sum of the thrown dice is at least X?

Comment: what type of dice ??

Comment: okay, now there won't be one probability, for all sums. So, hopefully you like algebra.

Comment: oh and what has been tried, might be a place to start showing.

Comment: You will get a cheerier reception on this site if you show what you have tried and with what you still need help.  You seem to be accumulating votes to 'close' your question because you haven't done that. Also it would be nice to know the level of the course in which this question was asked.  // In my answer, I have given you some clues toward an answer.

Comment: Why on earth is this question off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

The chance of hitting exactly sum $p$ with $n$ $s-$sided dice is:

$$P(p,n,s) = \frac{1}{s^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{p-sk-1}{n-1}$$

Summing from $x$ to $6n$ and substituting $s = 6$ gives:

$$\sum_{p=x}^{6n} \frac{1}{6^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{p-6k-1}{n-1}$$

$$\sum_{p=x}^{6n} \binom{p-6k-1}{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}\left((n+6k-x)\binom{x-6k-1}{n-1} + (5n-6k+1)\binom{6n-6k}{n-1}\right)$$

Giving the somewhat ugly closed form, but very efficient to evaluate:

$$ \frac{1}{n6^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left((n+6k-x)\binom{x-6k-1}{n-1} + (5n-6k+1)\binom{6n-6k}{n-1}\right)$$

Comment: This formula doesn't seem to work when n = 3 and x = 9 (the answer is supposed to be 20/27)

Comment: @user478136 And I correctly get 20/27. I believe you've made a clerical error.

Comment: $k$ only needs to go from $0$ to $\lfloor (p-n)/s \rfloor$ - see [Probabilies of rolling n dice to add up to a specific sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2304873/318073).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fair cubical dice with numbers 1 through 6, the PDF and CDF
for the sum $X$ on two dice is given in the table below.

```
     k:      2     3     4     5     6      7     8     9    10    11    12
P(X=k):   1/36  2/36  3/36  4/36  5/36  6/36   5/36  4/36  3/36  2/36  1/36
P(X<=k):  1/36  3/36  6/36 10/36 15/36  21/36 26/36 30/36 33/36 36/36   1
```

The CDF $P(X \le x)$ gives the probabilities that $X$ is *at most* $k,$ for $k = 2, 3, \dots, 12.$

I will leave it to you to add a line to the table that gives the probabilities
$P(X \ge k)$ for the relevant values of $k$. Then maybe you can deal with $N > 2$ dice.

You don't provide much context about the source of this problem. So it is
difficult to say whether you are supposed to use normal approximations,
symbolic software such as Mathematica, simulations in statistical
software, or a convolution formula.

Comment: I need a general formula so that I can find the probability for any value of n and x